# CIFeature has no member hasLeftEyePosition

Tags: swift, core-image

I am reading `GCD` tutorial from this https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1.

When I download the started project, and build, I got some error:

```
private extension PhotoDetailViewController {
  func faceOverlayImageFromImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace,
                     context: nil,
                     options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])

    // Get features from the image
    let newImage = CIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage!)
    let features = detector.featuresInImage(newImage)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

    // Draws this in the upper left coordinate system
    image.drawInRect(imageRect, blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha: 1.0)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    for faceFeature in features {
      let faceRect = faceFeature.bounds
      CGContextSaveGState(context)

      // CI and CG work in different coordinate systems, we should translate to
      // the correct one so we don't get mixed up when calculating the face position.
      CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, imageRect.size.height)
      CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)

      if faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition {
        let leftEyePosition = faceFeature.leftEyePosition
        let eyeWidth = faceRect.size.width / FaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor
        let eyeHeight = faceRect.size.height / FaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor
        let eyeRect = CGRect(x: leftEyePosition.x - eyeWidth / 2.0,
          y: leftEyePosition.y - eyeHeight / 2.0,
          width: eyeWidth,
          height: eyeHeight)
        drawEyeBallForFrame(eyeRect)
      }

      if faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition {
        let leftEyePosition = faceFeature.rightEyePosition
        let eyeWidth = faceRect.size.width / FaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor
        let eyeHeight = faceRect.size.height / FaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor
        let eyeRect = CGRect(x: leftEyePosition.x - eyeWidth / 2.0,
          y: leftEyePosition.y - eyeHeight / 2.0,
          width: eyeWidth,
          height: eyeHeight)
        drawEyeBallForFrame(eyeRect)
      }

      CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    let overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return overlayImage
  }
```

At this line `faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition`, it says:

> Value of type 'CIFeature' has no member 'hasLeftEyePosition'

So how to solve this.

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Only [`CIFaceFeature`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CIFaceFeature) has such a property. You need to cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the project you referred to and it's working for me (after updating it to the latest Swift version).

The important piece you're missing is in your 9th line where you set `features`:

```
let features = detector.featuresInImage(newImage)
```

This must be

```
let features = detector.featuresInImage(newImage) as! [CIFaceFeature]
```

I'm strongly against force casting, but since this not a production app I'm okay with it. If you want to make sure you never crash (in case someone changes the `CIDetectorType` from "face" to something else) you can guard it and return the input image instead:

```
guard let features = detector.featuresInImage(newImage) as? [CIFaceFeature] else { return image }
```

Comment: didn't work. When I change like your, it says `Use of undeclared identifier 'Utils'`

Comment: Yes it does work. That's another problem. You need to make `Utils` inherit from `NSObject`.